# Can I limit the number of connections for Mojo::IOLoop?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm using Mojo::UserAgent to make recursive calls to a web API.

At some point this fails - I suspect because the API has a limit on the number of calls from one client.

Is it possible to limit the number of concurrent calls that Mojo::IOLoop makes?

I'd like to be able to either limit or count and wait.

Here's the code that makes the calls:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();

my $loop = Mojo::IOLoop->singleton;
$loop->max_connections(100);
$loop->max_accepts(100);

my $url = Mojo::URL->new('https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx');
# authentication omitted

# start navigating the org tree
tree($ua, 'some.person@acme.com');

sub tree {
    my ($ua, $email) = @_;

    my $xml = $mt->vars(1)->render($template, { name =>  $email });

    my $tx = $ua->build_tx(POST => $url =>
           {
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml', 
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'None' 
            }
            => $xml);
    my $p = $ua->start_p($tx);

    $p->then(sub {
         my $tx = shift;
         my $dom = $tx->res->dom;
         my $reports = $dom->find('DirectReports Mailbox EmailAddress');
         if ($reports->size) {
             my @reports = @{$reports->map(sub { shift->all_text })->to_array};
             for (@reports) {
             print $email, $_;
             tree($ua, $_)
             }
         }
         })
    ->catch(sub {
            my $err = shift;
            warn "Connection error: $err";
            warn join ' ', @_;
    });
}

$loop->start;
```

and this is the template that gets posted:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ResolveNames xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
          SearchScope="ActiveDirectory"
          ContactDataShape="AllProperties"
                  ReturnFullContactData="true">
      <UnresolvedEntry><%= $name %></UnresolvedEntry>
    </ResolveNames>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This returns an XML file which contains - among other things - the emails of all of the direct reports, which are then used to recurse further. Can't post that, obviously.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. max_connections is used for limiting concurrent connections. It defaults to 1,000 and you are setting it to 100. https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop#max_connections

Comment: @UncleCarl it says _incoming connections_, not outgoing. This is a web crawler, not a web server.

Comment: This is not the full code. How does the `$loop` know what to run?

Comment: @simbabque - This _is_ the full code, save for omittinug URLs and similar that would give away too much context. I'll confess to ignorance and cargo-culting. My goal is to recursively make requests to the API which gives me org-tree connections. However the API refuses to handle more than a certain amount of connections (probably ~100) concurrently - and that's what I'm trying to throttle. Maybe in the wrong way - apologies.

Comment: Just add some example.org URLs. I don't understand how the program starts. With that, I might be able to help.

Comment: @simbabque  added more code - hope that helps

Comment: Are you trying to talk to an Exchange? Does the regular API client we have on CPAN not work for you? I've used that productively and have some knowledge on how to extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [Mojo::UserAgent::Role::Queued](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent::Role::Queued), but here's the entire module:

```
package Mojo::UserAgent::Role::Queued;
use Mojo::Base '-role';
use Scalar::Util 'weaken';

our $VERSION = "1.10";
use Mojo::UserAgent::Role::Queued::Queue;

has max_active => sub { shift->max_connections };

around start => sub {
  my ($orig, $self, $tx, $cb) = @_;
  state $queue //= Mojo::UserAgent::Role::Queued::Queue->new(
    max_active => $self->max_active,
    callback   => sub { $self->$orig(@_); }
  );
  if ($cb) {
    $tx->on(finish => sub { $queue->tx_finish(); });
    $queue->on( queue_empty => sub { $self->emit('queue_empty') });
    $queue->enqueue([$tx, $cb]);
  }
  else {
    return $orig->($self, $tx);    # Blocking calls skip the queue
  }
};
```

It creates a queue that knows how many connections it can work on simultaneously. It wraps the `start` so it doesn't run until the connection count drops below your threshold.

I've done similar things with rate limiting by counting the connections in the last time period.

Comment: Yeeeah! Just a second before I was about to implement it with a Minion queue. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend using the actual module, because this isn't the full code - it uses a tiny utility class (:::Queue) which isn't reproduced here. Also, the current version  (1.15) removed the use of state to create the queue, which had the weird side-effect of making your Mojo::UserAgent object into a singleton.